# How can I handle delegates in my view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I use the code below to handle row clicks in Telerik GridView, how can I handle the `delegate` for this method in my view model instead of handling OnRowMouseDown in my view?

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(GridViewRow), GridViewRow.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnRowMouseDown), true);
```

The parameter `new RoutedEventHandler(OnRowMouseDown)` is a `delegate`.

Comment: Does `GridViewRow.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent` compile?

Comment: Yes, it is a Telerik control

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the actual event using an event handler with a specific signature.

What you can do is to call a method of your view model from the event handler, i.e. in `OnRowMouseDown`:

```
var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModel;
viewModel.SomeMethod();
```

The call to `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(GridViewRow), GridViewRow.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnRowMouseDown), true);` in the view stays the same and so does the signature of `OnRowMouseDown`. You just move the logic from the event handler to the view model. This is what MVVM is all about basically.

Comment: I thought having the ViewModel referenced in the Views code behind breaks the MVVM design pattern? Is there not a way to use binding?

Comment: Why would referencing a view model from a view break the pattern? Calling the view model from the code-behind is no different from calling it or binding to it from the XAML markup of the same view.

Comment: You could use an attached behaviour that registers the event handler and invokes a command if you don't want to use code-behind but it doesn't break the pattern. You could actually impelement an entire view in code-behind without using any XAML at all without breaking MVVM.